# TemplateSyntaxError at / Invalid block tag on line 57: 'logout_url', expected 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am building an app in Django 3.1.4.

I dont' understand why I am getting

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag on line 57: 'logout_url', expected 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

highlighting this line:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% logout_url %}">Logout</a>
```

Here is my code,
In my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
]
```

In my template:

```
{% url 'logout' as logout_url %}

      {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == login_url %}active{% endif %}">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == register_url %}active{% endif %}">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
      </li>
      {% else %}

      <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == admin_url %}active{% endif %}">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == logout_url %}active{% endif %}"></li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% logout_url %}">Logout</a>
        <!-- logout_url -->
      </li>
      {% endif %}
```

It works fine if I just substitute the part:

```
  <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == logout_url %}active{% endif %}"></li>
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% logout_url %}">Logout</a>
  </li>
```

with:

```
  <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == logout_url %}active{% endif %}"></li>
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
  </li>
```

But I don't understand why...

It's like line

```
{% url 'logout' as logout_url %}
```

is not working at all, 
and more, django expects for `{% endif %}`.
So does it mean code breaks down at a certain point and cannot read the `{% endif %}` tag?

Can anybody explain me what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

I was using django custom "function, cycle, condition, ecc." tag syntax (`{%  %}`) intead of django variable tag syntax (`{{ }}`) .

I had to substitute

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% logout_url %}">Logout</a>
```

with:

```
   <a class="nav-link" href="{{ logout_url }}">Logout</a>
```